# Life of Adam and Eve

Tags: prophet-muhammad, christianity, judaism, prophet-adam

Salam,

I read about a book called the "Life of Adam and Eve" - which contains the story of Adam alaihi salam being prostrated before by the Angels. It seems to be from the first century? I am wondering how I should respond to creeping doubts, as it's argued that Muhammad Salla Allahu Alaihi Was Salam heard these stories and legends and incorporated it in the Qur'an, especially with the polemical nature of the Qur'an which seems to assume a fully knowing reader at times.

Comment: Which doubts are creeping within you?

Comment: Why the there would be apocryphal literature dated from the 1st century that is the only source that speaks of the prostration by the angels towards Adam (as) is my worry.

Comment: Bigger question is why shouldn't there be? Obviously, it is the truth even if not recorded in the current Torah. The apocryphal literature simply proves the Jews and Christians knew of some of it through oral traditions

Answer (score -2):

There are several writings on this which I would call "religious fiction". They are based on the Torah (Genesis 2), some revelation that I suspect has been revealed to Parsic prophets now unknown, and a lot of phantasy.

The Quran often refers to stories supposed to be known by the reader as an example for the actual message, where not the story itself is the message but the message that follows is.